# How can I get a TextBox text in another thread?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm doing all crazy stuff today :D I tried invoking it by

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    username = UsernameInput.Text;
                });
```

But that does not seem to work :( And how do I also set a value cross thread?

Comment: I have a doubt regarding your answer. Since the BeginInvoke takes time fire, the value of the Text might be changed by that time. Don't you think it would be feasible to pass the Text as parameter to the delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by sleeping the thread for a second after Dispather. Guess you have to allow the gui thread to "answer" the other thread.

Answer (score 1):

I did this some time ago, don't know if it's the right way to do it but it works tho:

```
Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    // Code...
});
```